# What is BMDongleService

Tags: macos

Anyone know what this process is? I've seen it in ApplicationSupport/BM

It's been running two thread and using 100% cpu.

Cancelled it a few times and it comes back. Absolutely nothing about it online.

No virus scanners or malware programs I've run have picked anything up.

Since I've trashed it for now, but curious to know what it is. Nothing has stopped working.

Comment: Um. Do you have a dongle plugged in to your Mac?

Comment: (As in, is there some sort of USB or Thunderbolt device you have to attach to your computer in order to run some specific software? Or maybe a smart card or other type of digital fob?)

Comment: Could "BM" be "Black Magic"? Did or do you use DaVinci Resolve?

Comment: Think it could be Black Magic. Odd that there are zero references to it online given how popular Davinci Resolve is and the associated Black Magic tools.

Comment: I have the same process too, were you able to figure out what installed it?